# Using $\epsilon^2$ for proving limits

Tags: real-analysis

This is a real simple question, and I think there is no problem with this, but I'm just checking.

> Is it okay to use $\epsilon^2$ for proof in the $\epsilon-\delta$ proof, etc, instead of $\epsilon$?

So for example, if you want to show that a sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to a certain limit $L$, would this work?

> For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a positive integer $N$, s.t, for every $k>N$,
> $$|a_k-L|<\epsilon^2$$

Comment: Yes, it is OK because given any $\eta >0$ we can find $\epsilon >0$ with $\epsilon^{2}<\eta$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is fine. The symbol $\epsilon$ really just refers to an arbitrary positive real number, and is a way to specify an intuitively "arbitrarily small" neighbourhood of a point. Thus, using $\epsilon$, or $\epsilon^2$, or even $2^\epsilon$, etc. are all OK. However, we conventionally use $\epsilon$ for the sake of simplicity.

Edit: To be precise, if you want to use something like $2^\epsilon$ then you have to let $\epsilon$ be any real number in order for $2^\epsilon$ to be an arbitrary *positive* real number (if $\epsilon>0$, then $2^\epsilon>1$). But obviously it is best to avoid all these problems, which is why we conventionally use $\epsilon$.

Comment: i have an issue with using $2^{\epsilon}$ but not with using $2^{-1/\epsilon}$.  also, using $5\epsilon$ or $\epsilon/2$ or $10^{10}\epsilon$, etc would work as well

Comment: @CSquared What's wrong with using $2^\epsilon$? Am I missing something?

Comment: yea. $2^{\epsilon}$ is a bit misleading in this context. you even say it in your answer. we want to capture the notion of specifying an arbitrarily small neighborhood of a point. but for $\epsilon>0$, $2^{\epsilon}$ does not get arbitrarily close to $0$. the smallest neighborhood you can approach with that is a neighborhood or radius $1$

Comment: @CSquared Yes, but logically speaking it is okay, if we allow $\epsilon$ to be any real number. Of course it is nonconventional for the reason that you mentioned, but that was sort of the point.

Comment: agreed. i guess i was mislead, since in your initial answer it seems like you are actually imposing that $\epsilon>0$

Comment: @CSquared Thanks, it was a good point. Edited to reflect that.